# Error when using dropdownlist (with int-based item values) as a filter for data table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC5 app I have a table with data in it. Above the table I have a simple dropdownlist, to be used as a filter for the data, filtering by (int) branchId.

I'm filling the branchId dropdownlist via the viewbag...

```
 ViewBag.Branch = db.Branches
   .ToList()
   .Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Id.ToString(), Text = rr.BranchName })
   .ToList();
```

Here's the dropdownlist....

```
@Html.DropDownList("branchId", 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Branch, 
     "-- All Branches --")
```

On my POST method I'm trying to filter the data....

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult GetEventsByUser(int? branchId)
    {
        :
        IQueryable<Event> events;
        events = db.Events;
        :
        if (branchId != null)
        {
            events = events
                .Include(a => a.Branch)
                .Where(b => Equals(b.Branch.Id, branchId));
        }
        else
        {
            events = events
                .Include(a => a.Branch);
        }
        :
        :
        return View("Index", events.ToList());
```

The error occurs on the last line. The error is:

```
Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. 
LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
```

How can I use the dropdown as a filter for this int based field?

Comment: did you tried '.Where(b => b.Branch.Id == branchId)' ?

Comment: @user1845593 that was it! How can I give you credit? Thanks! :)

Comment: That's fine. I can post a solution just to keep the record. Most people ignore the comments. Just a suggestion for future posts. Give it a suggestive name, like the name of the error for example, something generic and not specific to you

Comment: Thanks @user1845593 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to the Equals, which is not supported by LINQ, change it to ==.

```
       events = events
            .Include(a => a.Branch)
            .Where(b => b.Branch.Id == branchId);
```